# AWS SDK for Java v2.0 - using S3 CRT Async Client, s3Client.putObject fails with InvalidStateException after 10 seconds of hanging

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-s3-client

I'm using AWS SDK for Java v2.0, S3 Async Client with the `aws-crt` library, which allows to easily put objects with undetermined size as it uses multi-part transfer internally.

Occasionally it fails with this error message, exactly 10 seconds after the putObject call:

```
The service request was not made within 10 seconds of doBlockingWrite being invoked. Make sure to invoke the service request BEFORE invoking doBlockingWrite if your caller is single-threaded.
```

I've linked the error to [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/df4753216daeb119408f7378ec68c3cb1d0824d7/core/sdk-core/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody.java#L107), but I fail to understand what exactly is wrong.

The S3 Client is initialized as a single instance like so:

```java
S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.crtBuilder()
                    .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .region(region)
                    .minimumPartSizeInBytes(8L * 1024 * 1024)
                    .build();
```

The application is technically single threaded, but it does process the long task lists via Java streams, although it runs on an AWS Fargate cluster with 0.25 vcpus, so if I read the docs correctly, the fork-join pool will only have a single thread.

Initially I suspected that this is since I have not set up `maxConcurrency` to be large enough, but the default is 50, which is more than the available CPUs anyway.

I have set `maxconcurrency` to a high value of 100, but it is hard to verify whether this worked, as the problem occurs only occasionally, and I'd appreciate any insight that is more concrete.

Comment: Welcome. Can you link to this library please? I assume the issue isn't happening with the SDK on its own so this is really a question regarding library implementation.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary- the `aws-crt` library is provided by Amazon (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/common-runtime.html, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-crt-based-s3-client-and-the-s3-transfer-manager-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/ https://central.sonatype.com/namespace/software.amazon.awssdk.crt), it is an alternative implementation of the low level library.

Comment: Ah interesting! I've never used the CRT client - let me take a look.

Comment: I did find this issue reported on the library: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-java/issues/665.
It might be the solution